# Конвертирование String в StringBuilder и обратно

Tags: c#, строки

Есть некий метод, который получает в качестве параметра довольно большую стринговину (порядка `50000` символов и более). Метод разбивает полученную строку на слова посредством `Split(" ")` и мы получаем стринговый массив. Далее каждое слово в массиве предстоит изменениям: некоторые символы заменяем на другие символы, некоторые удаляем и т.д. Короче говоря предстоит куча работы со строками, а значит  нужно прибегать к помощи класса `StringBuilder`. Парвильно ли я понимаю: нужно `String` конвертировать каким-то образом в `StringBuilder`, совершить все необходимые операции и обратно конвертироваться в `String`? Если да, как сделать с `S=>SB`? Стоит ли при таком количестве строк каждую операцию по изменению выносить в отдельный метод? Как по человечески это реализовать с наименьшими потерями производительности?

Comment: `new StringBuilder(s)` `sb.ToString()`

Comment: Всё зависит от того, какая именно работа будет выполняться со строками. Может оказаться, что перегонка в StringBuilder и обратно невыгодна. Или, например, нужно корректно обрабатывать суррогатные пары, (де)нормализованный текст и т. п., для чего придётся использовать классы StringInfo, TextInfo и др. То есть StringBuilder здесь неприменим. В общем, много нюансов. Опишите подробнее, что именно делаете, с кодом. Тогда есть шанс, что получите конкретный ответ.

Comment: ```
AtomicReference<StringBuilder> sb = new AtomicReference<>(new StringBuilder(str[i]));
```
при работе с массивами.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю в `StringBuilder`, его стоит использовать, когда вы конструируете и изменяете довольно большие строки. В очень сильном приближении сам `StringBuilder` можно рассматривать как массив мелких строк. Поэтому если вы уже работаете небольшими строками, собранными в большой массив, и меняете в них символы не часто, то особого выигрыша от использования `StringBuilder` у вас, возможно, и не будет, вы только потеряете время на лишнюю конвертацию туда-обратно. Ну и понятность кода несколько уменьшится из-за этих конвертаций.